# Inserting data into ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to insert data into ms access

I have rechecked the code many times seems nothing wrong

```
    private void registerbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            registerconnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand();
            insert.Connection = registerconnection;
            insert.CommandText = "insert into StudentDatabase (FirstName, LastName, DOB, City, State, Email, ContactNo, ContactNo2, Courses, Username, Password, DateRegister) values ('"+fnametextbox.Text+ "','" + lnametextbox.Text + "','" + dobtextbox.Text + "','" + citytextbox.Text + "','" + statetextbox.Text + "','" + emailtextbox.Text + "','" + ctcnotextbox.Text + "','" + ctcnotextbox2.Text + "','" + coursetextbox.Text + "','" + usernametextbox.Text + "','" + passwordtextbox.Text + "','" + registerdatetextbox.Text + "')";
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");
    }
```

I expected it was able to insert the data but it turns out into an error

Comment: Create a variable with your SQL statement, print it to debug/console and check in SQL editor - you'll find an error details. E.g. you can have `'` sign in textbox, that is the root of sql injections, that breaks the query structure

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Password is a keyword and must be escaped with square brackets in Access. Change Password to [Password]. More importantly, your open to SQL injection and need to change your code over to use parameters, this will also help with problems on how to denote value types  (ie, ' ' for strings, # # for dates, etc...)

Comment: If you already know what the error says then please tell us what it is...why make us guess or figure it out? Make it easy for people to help you...

Comment: However, on a wider point I also suggest you read [this](https://bobby-tables.com/) to understand why your code is a big security Risk. And then you can read [this](https://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) to start understanding how you overcome that risk by using proper parameterised queries. Make sure you follow the OLE DB examples. You can find plenty more examples if you search more widely online. (As a side benefit it will also help you avoid trivial syntax errors due to unexpected input values, incorrect escaping of strings etc.)

Comment: @ADyson the error message states that "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Comment: Try doing `MessageBox.Show(insert.CommandText);` just after the `insert.CommandText =...` line so you can see the final query being generated. Then it might be easier to see the mistake. As mentioned above, it could be your use of a keyword such as "Password", or it could be something else. Since we can't see your final query text, we can't tell you for certain. But you definitely need to look closely at the final query, and make sure you understand the rules of Access syntax as well as you can. And also start to use parameterised queries as above - it can help reduce syntax & security errors

Answer (score -1):

This shall help you...I did not test the code but i assume it will work.

http://dotnetsridhar.blogspot.com/2012/05/ma-access-database-for-windows-c.html

also check your textbox input value , some special character was a reserved character in SQL , example ';  ,  if user type those special character on textbox and process by your current code logic , it may break because you try to add all string value without proper input validation handle and it may fail as a valid SQL statement...debugger will be your good friend here to diagnose further what is the "insert.CommandText" value